# Conditional Border Style VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

trying to change the border style of a picture box when the corresponding checkbox is selected is this possible?

```
If chkRadioMic.Checked = True Then
        dblCostOfFacilities += 10 And
        picRadioMic = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    End If
```

Many thanks

Comment: What is that `And` operator you put there?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have pretty basic understanding of VB.NET and programming in general. Your code should look like this:

```
If chkRadioMic.Checked Then
    dblCostOfFacilities += 10.0R
    picRadioMic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
End If
```

assuming that the type of `dblCostOfFacilities` is `System.Double`.